# jsdom not triggering internal <script>

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, jsdom

I am trying to sample a page that has a script on it that changes the CSS of certain elements such that an attribute toggles between "active" and "inactive" based on the width of the window.

I have written nodeJS code that gathers and analyzes the page, but I cannot seem to trigger, or detect the triggering of the script.  I suspect it has to do with defaultDocumentFeatures, but I could be wrong.

The script opens the page in JSDOM with a default width, then changes it to a specified block of other widths.  This should result in changes in the output, but it does not.  I am getting the same results for all situations.  I suspect that the script on the page simply isn't running, but need help to make it do so

Here is my code (expurgated for public viewing.)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jsdom=require('jsdom');

router.get('/getSamplePage', function(req, res) {
    getaEpicPage(req, res, function(contents){ 
        console.log("got an sample page"+contents+"000000000");
        //contents gets replaced by the actual results that will be processed upstream
        res.send({'msg':'', 'contents':contents});
            });
});



var getaSamplePage=function (req, res, callback) {
    jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures={
        FetchExternalResources      : ['script', 'css'],
        ProcessExternalResources    : ['script', 'css'],
        MutationEvents              : '2.0',
        QuerySelector               : false
    };
    var elementLocations=[
                    'sample_01',
                    'sample_02',
                    'sample_03'];

    var contents=[{label:'DIV ID', value:'Is Populated', width: "Screen Width", position:"element size"}];
    var windowWidths=[
        479,
        481,
        781,
        783,
        1023,
        1025,
        ]
    for (var i in windowWidths){
        jsdom.env({
            url:'http://sourcefilelocation/',
            scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'],
            created: function(errors, tstWindow) {
                tstWindow.tstWindowWidth=windowWidths.pop();
                tstWindow.addEventListener('resize', function() {
                    //verify that resize is triggered
                    console.log('Resize event completed');
                });
                tstWindow.constructor.prototype.resize = function (width){
                    //defining a "resize" event, since that may be what triggers things
                    console.log("resize has been attempted");
                    tstWindow.originalWidth=tstWindow.innerWidth;
                    tstWindow.outerWidth=tstWindow.innerWidth=width;
                }
                tstWindow.readyState="complete";

            },
            done: function(errors, tstWindow) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    //setting a timeout to ensure that any elements have finished I have put this as high as ten seconds.
                    console.log("ready state "+tstWindow.readyState);
                    tstWindow.resize(tstWindow.tstWindowWidth)

                    $=tstWindow.$;
                    for (var sampleLocation in sampleLocations) {
                        var sampleID=sampleLocations[sampleLocation];
                        $('div > [sampleAttribute='+sampleID+']').each(function(){
                            //If the script I am trying to watch work triggers, it should change the "content" attribute
                            var elementActive=$(this).css('content');
                            var position=$(this).attr('sample-position');
                            console.log("element css>>>>>>  "+tstWindow.innerWidth+" "+sampleID+" "+position+" "+elementActive);
                            if (elementActive=='"active"'){
                                contents.push({label:sampleID, value: elementActive, width: tstWindow.originalWidth+"/"+tstWindow.innerWidth, position:position});
                            }
                            });
                    };
                }, 50);
            }


            });
    };
    setTimeout(function () { callback(contents);}, 100);
};

module.exports = router;
```

Per suggestion I added this to my jsDom config object, just after the url:

```
    FetchExternalResources      : ['script', 'css'],
    ProcessExternalResources    : ['script', 'css'],
    MutationEvents              : '2.0',
    QuerySelector               : false,
```

But it has made no apparent difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [jsdom Readme](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#on-running-scripts-and-being-safe) when you're using `jsdom.env` the default feature set does not include processing scripts.

You have to pass the `FetchExternalResources` and `ProcessExternalResources` to `jsdom.env` specifically.

```
jsdom.env({
  html: input,
  url: url,
  features: {
    FetchExternalResources: ["script", "img", "css", "frame", "iframe", "link"],
    ProcessExternalResources: ["script"]
  },
  created: function (err, window) {
      console.log('Created');
  },

  loaded: function (err, window) {
    console.log('Loaded');
  }
});
```

`jsdom.env` doesn't use the `jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures` object.

Comment: Does that continue to be true with the 1.0 version?

Comment: But I tried added the relevant lines to the config object, please see my edits, and it does not seem to have made a difference.

Comment: @SkipHuffman Did you wrap the properties in a `features` object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  I added the four feature attributes to the config object that I am passing to jsDom.env

Comment: @SkipHuffman See [here](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/test/w3c/w3ctest.js#L21) on how to correctly provide jsdom with these parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try later today.

Comment: Could I pretty please get a link to the documentation where it says jsdom.env does not use jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures??